# How to color individual parts of curve in unity, real time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, blender, mesh

So I have a mesh curve that I've imported from Blender. What I want to do is to place individual points on the curve (at fixed distance) and then based on a specific number, color them.

Let's say for instance number 1000 is color red and number 10 is color blue (based on color gradient). These numbers get updated real time, so I want my color to get updated real time.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I've looked up some ideas but couldn't find anything useful.

[image]

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @JoeBlow there you go: http://prntscr.com/bpm3yw

Comment: @JoeBlow it could be a rope. not necessarily though.

Comment: @JoeBlow it's for a visualization application. so imagine something like this. http://www.west-racing.com/mf/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ytfumefx.jpg
it's just when it reads the data it changes something to red or green on that certain point

Comment: Forget the line you created in blender. Try LineRenderer: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html but if it doesn't give you enough details or too slow, you should do your thing (with math) via GL: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html

Comment: Mark, it's a good pointer but LineRenderer is pretty useless.  Every single Unity developer uses **Vectrosity** so you'll need to get that no matter what.  Indeed I'm thinking, @2222 - if I was you, I'd email the makers of Vectrosity, and explain your problem.  I bet, they'd have an approach for you.

Comment: @JoeBlow I disagree with you regarding LineRenderer as it has it's uses. 2222: here's an example of GL.LINES: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96964/how-to-correctly-draw-a-line-in-unity  (yes, you need to use shaders with it, but the good news is, the example provides that too!). BTW Joe is right on Unity might not be the best tool if you want what I/we assume you want (did you try Wolfram Alpha?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, it's by no means easy to do this.

Unity is a game engine - it's just not relevant to that type of problem you know?

I believe the only real solution would be **to do it at the shader level**.

As you know writing shaders is a whole engineering field in itself.  I suggest, just google things like "Unity3d color gradient, shader" in the first instance.

For example,

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1108472/3-color-linear-gradient-shader.html

---

One thing you can conceivably do. Make the rope white. **Apply lights to it!** So, colored narrow beam lights or carefully placed diffuse lights. Perhaps in conjunction with layers for the lighting. It's not inconceivable it could work, enjoy!

Note - in fact the OP solved the problem just using colored lights - a solution in some cases.

---

Please note, the GL api is perfect here also.

user2299169 gives an outstanding link in the comments above:

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96964/how-to-correctly-draw-a-line-in-unity

GL Doco: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html

Thanks user2299169.

Comment: Was about to write up a similar thing, I think a shader is the only reasonable way to solve the problem, after all the problem of changing pixel colors dynamically on shapes is what shaders where invented to solve.

Comment: Right. Totally agreed, Scott.  There's one other "smart ass" solution I'll put in...!

Comment: Vertex colors might work also, can update them easily using script and/or modify in shader

Comment: @JoeBlow I used spotlight